# ConTeXt: How do align my cows in the margin vertically?

Tags: margins, context, framed

In my MWE, I put 2 cows in the margin.

Top cow: I understand why the cow juts above the margin. Can I move the cow down (while still using an `\inmargin`), so that the top of the cow is at the top of the margin ?

Bottom cow: I used framed text, `location=hanging`, to move the frame and the cow down. But I think it has moved it down a line too far. Can I have the top of the frame level with the top of the line 'Text after dobesideimage.' ?
[image]

```
\showframe
\setupexternalfigures[location=default] % get the cow
%\setuppapersize[A4][A3,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE]

\setuplayout[backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=200mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]

\definemargindata[mymarginnote][left]
    [margin=margin,width=\leftmarginwidth,style={\ss},align=high, ]

\define[3]\dobesideimage% in left margin: image with optional text  below 
    {\mymarginnote
        {\framedtext [width=\leftmarginwidth, offset=0mm,location=hanging,]
            {#1\\ \externalfigure[#2][width=\leftmarginwidth]\\#3}
        }   
    } 

\starttext 

\inmargin{\externalfigure[cow][width=\leftmarginwidth]\\I didn’t need a clock, but it was there, and l could, so l did. }

\dorecurse{1}{\input{tufte} }

Text before dobesideimage.

\dobesideimage {Text before cow.}{cow}{So, l recently bought a small clock. I didn’t need a clock, but it was there, and l could, so l did. }

Text after dobesideimage.

\dorecurse{1}{\input{tufte} }

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is better to use the built-in mechanisms as much as possible, since they are there to help. I do not understand exactly what you are after, but what I suggest below can perhaps be a start? Observe the `high` key in the location of the figures. Also, note the `\movesidefloat` that is used to push the second image down a bit.

```
\showframe
\setupexternalfigures[location=default] % get the cow

\setuplayout[backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=200mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]

\starttext 

\startplacefigure
  [location={inleft,high,nonumber},
   title={I didn’t need a clock, but it was there, and l could, so l did.}]
  \externalfigure[cow][width=\leftmarginwidth]
\stopplacefigure
\dorecurse{1}{\samplefile{tufte} }

Text before dobesideimage.

\setupmargindata
  [inleftmargin]
  [style=sans,
   align=flushleft]

\inleftmargin{Text before cow}

\setupcaptions
  [style=sans]

\setupcaption
  [inleft]
  [width=\leftmarginwidth,
   align=flushleft]

\movesidefloat[2*line]
\startplacefigure
  [location={inleft,high,nonumber},
   title={So, l recently bought a small clock. I didn’t need a clock, but it was there, and l could, so l did.}]
   \externalfigure[cow][width=\leftmarginwidth]
\stopplacefigure

Text after dobesideimage.

\dorecurse{1}{\samplefile{tufte} }

\stoptext
```

[image: cows in the margin]

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Great. I thought that something simpler than a float would do. In general, I distrust floats, because sometimes they have floated to unexpected places. I realise that this is what TeX is meant to do. I see from your avatar you have been going to Christmas parties.